# HTML Email : padding not working in gmail

Tags: html, css, html-table

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">
      <span style="color: black; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:100 !important; letter-spacing: 8px; font-size: 35px;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;">TIECON</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">
      <span style="color: black; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:100 !important; letter-spacing: 8px; font-size: 35px;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;">AHMEDABAD</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">
      <span style="color: black; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:100 !important; letter-spacing: 8px; font-size: 35px;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;">2016</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can see padding in browser but not in **gmail**.

[image: image with padding]

[image: image without padding in gmail]

PS: As I am making HTML Emailer, I have to stick to `table` and **inline css** , only.

Thank You.

Comment: Try to add paddings to the table cells. Sometimes gmail interferes with styling.

Comment: try to using `line-height:35px` css

Comment: @MinalChauhan ... Thank You.. It worked. thanx a lot.. :)

Comment: @user123 plz accept as answer ... glad to helping.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to using `line-height:35px`

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">
      <span style="color: black; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:100 !important; letter-spacing: 8px; font-size: 35px;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif; line-height:35px;">TIECON</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">
      <span style="color: black; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:100 !important; letter-spacing: 8px; font-size: 35px;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;line-height:35px;">AHMEDABAD</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">
      <span style="color: black; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:100 !important; letter-spacing: 8px; font-size: 35px;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;line-height:35px;">2016</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding in Gmail works only for the td element. So simply specify a padding to your td elements inside the table element.